# Grouping list element in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following list:

```
List<string> data = new List<string>();
```

Then I populate it by fetching the result of a MySQL request:

```
data.Add(name);
```

The list is well populated but I would like to make a grouping, and would like to get the number of each name present in the list:

```
name A = X;
name B = X; 
etc...
```

I tried to do it using `data.GroupBy(data, data.Count)` but did not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not grouping as part of your SQL query?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from d in data
group d by d.Name into gds
select new
{
    Name = gds.Key,
    Count = gds.Count(),
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string[] foo = new string[]{"foo","foo","bar","foo","baz","foo"};

var grouping = foo.ToList().GroupBy(x=>x);

foreach (var s in grouping.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Count()))
{
    Console.WriteLine(s.Key + " - " + s.Count().ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys, 

the solution of p.campbell did the job and was the closest to what I was looking for...

Crak

Comment: @Crak Thanks Crak; be sure to use the green checkmark as it's part of the Q&A and reputation systems on StackOverflow. Thanks!